# Installing pyipopt, encounter fatal error: IpStdCInterface.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, compiling

This question is in the context of an attempt to install a library/interface on Ubuntu. It is a very specific problem, but any general help (such as in deciphering which script, or where in a particular script, the error is coming from) would also be greatly appreciated. I'm rather new to Ubuntu and this forum so please let me know if this is an irrelevant question (or if there are any other issues)!

**Background**

I am trying to install [pyipopt](https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt) on Ubuntu, after having installed [Ipopt](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html). Ipopt is a library and pyipopt is meant to interface between the library and python. The directories for pyipopt and Ipopt are separate. I have edited `setup.py` for pyipopt. One of the edits made in `setup.py` was to specify the path to which the Ipopt library was installed. I then ran `python3 setup.py build` as instructed on the pyipopt github (linked above). This is the error it produces:

```
[myusername]:~/pyipopt$ python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pyipoptcore' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/bandgeek108/Ipopt_coinbrew/~/Ipopt_coinbrew/include/coin/ -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/callback.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/callback.o
In file included from src/callback.c:36:
src/hook.h:5:10: fatal error: IpStdCInterface.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include "IpStdCInterface.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

**What I have tried so far**

I have done some rooting around, and have managed to find `IpStdCInterface.h` so I know it exists. However, I don't know how I can "help" the script to find this file. The missing file is in the path `~/Ipopt_coinbrew/Ipopt/src/Interfaces`, whereas the path to the Ipopt library which I specified in `setup.py` was `~/Ipopt_coinbrew/~/Ipopt_coinbrew` ; I suspect this is why the pyipopt build script is unable to find the required file. However if I broaden the path in `setup.py` to just `~/Ipopt_coinbrew`, another error is produced:

```
[myusername]:~/pyipopt$ python3 setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 36, in <module>
    raise Exception('failed to find ipopt lib')
Exception: failed to find ipopt lib
```

I have also tried to copy the `Interfaces` directory into the original path which I had specified in `setup.py`, but the same first error occurs (still unable to find the file).

Does anyone know of any other methods I could try?

**Edit:**
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 which was the default version when I downloaded from the Windows store a few weeks back.

Furthermore, I have been trying more methods over the past few days and reinstalled Ipopt into `/usr/local/lib`. The missing file is now found in `/usr/local/include/coin-or`. However, running build with the IPOPT directory in `setup.py` set to `/usr/local` still gives the same first error (unable to find StdCInterface.h).

Comment: To start with, which Ubuntu release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.